# When loading a .fbx, I get that "worldMatrices" is undefined

Tags: three.js, load, fbx

```
TypeError: worldMatrices is undefined
Traza de la pila:
parseScene@file:///C:/Users/Guillermo%20P/Proyectos/Blank%20Null%201.0/blankNull/10.0.0.3/js/FBXLoader2.js:1384:10
parse@file:///C:/Users/Guillermo%20P/Proyectos/Blank%20Null%201.0/blankNull/10.0.0.3/js/FBXLoader2.js:115:21
load/<@file:///C:/Users/Guillermo%20P/Proyectos/Blank%20Null%201.0/blankNull/10.0.0.3/js/FBXLoader2.js:59:18
load/<@https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js:621:455
```

That's the error. I'm exporting from 3ds max 2015 in ASCII format. I'm trying to look up for any info about this, but no resuilts come up, not even a 3ds max guide on how to define the "world matrix".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is an old version of the format.

You can see header of FBXLoader.js

```
* Requires FBX file to be >= 7.0 and in ASCII or to be any version in Binary format.
```

So the best way is to re-export the model in a newer version of the FBX format or convert it to a different format such as glTF then load the file, you can refer [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf)